# save/load for textRPG with json

Tags: python, text, save, load

I'm attmpting to make a save load function for my text RPG it will save and load a single load on open and save on close. This textRPG is my first real project. right now I'm just trying to get the file to dump to a json.

the code im using is this

```
def saveload():
        player_Stats = {
        player.hp,
        player.gold,
        player.lvl,
        player.current_location()
     }
    filename = 'save.json'
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(player_Stats)
```

this is the whole player script. I plan on using json.load later to load the data into the respective variables right now in the save function iv only got a couple of the players stats to save for testing purposes. any help is appreciated.

```
import items
import world
import enemies
import magic

class Player:

def __init__(self):
    self.inventory = [items.Dagger(),items.Rock(),items.CrustyBread()]
    self.spell_book = [magic.magic_missle(), magic.fire_ball()]
    self.x = world.start_tile_location[0]
    self.y = world.start_tile_location[1]
    self.hp = 100
    self.gold = 5
    self.victory = False
    self.exp = 199
    self.player_lvl = 1
    self.mana = 100
def is_alive(self):

    return self.hp > 0 
def move(self,dx,dy):
    self.x += dx
    self.y += dy
def move_north(self):
    self.move(dx=0, dy=-1)
def move_south(self):
    self.move(dx=0, dy=1)
def move_east(self):
    self.move(dx=1, dy=0)
def move_west(self):
    self.move(dx=-1, dy=0)
def player_stats(self):
    print("Level: {}".format(self.player_lvl), "HP: {}".format(self.hp),"Mana:{}".format(self.mana),"Gold: {}".format(self.gold), "EXP: {}".format(self.exp))
def print_spellbook(self):
    print('\n Spell Book')
    for magic in self.spell_book:
        print('*'+str(magic))

def print_inventory(self):
    print("\n Inventory:")
    for item in self.inventory:
        print('* ' + str(item))
    print("Gold: {}".format(self.gold))


'''
def check_lvl_up(self,enemy):
    new_exp = self.exp + enemy.exp
    levels = [0,200,450,1012]
    if True:
        current_level = sum(1 for x in levels if x<= total_exp)
        self.player_lvl = current_level
'''
def most_powerful_weapon(self):
    max_damage = 0 
    best_weapon = None
    for item in self.inventory: 
        try:
            if item.damage > max_damage:
                best_weapon = item 
                max_damage = item.damage
                if self.player_lvl >= 2:
                    item.damage = item.damage + 1
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    return best_weapon
def attack(self):

    spell = [magic_spell for magic_spell in self.spell_book if isinstance(magic_spell,magic.Spell)]
    if not spell:
        print("You have no spells to cast!")
    
    user_input = input('What do you want to attack with? Melee or Magic: ')

    if user_input == str('magic'):
        for i, magic_spell in enumerate(spell, 1):
            print("Choose a spell to cast: ")
            print("{}. {}".format(i,magic_spell))
        
        valid =False
        while not valid:
            choice = input("")
            try:
                if self.mana == 0:
                    print("You dont have enough mana")
                else:   
                    room = world.tile_at(self.x,self.y)
                    enemy = room.enemy
                    print("You use {} against {}!".format(magic_spell,enemy.name))
                    enemy.hp -= magic_spell.damage
                    self.mana = self.mana - magic_spell.mana

                    if not enemy.is_alive():
                        print("You killed {}!".format(enemy.name))
                        
                    else:
                        print("{} HP is {}.".format(enemy.name,enemy.hp))
            except(ValueError,IndexError):
                print("Invalid choice, try again")  
            break
    elif user_input == str('melee'):
        best_weapon = self.most_powerful_weapon()
        room = world.tile_at(self.x,self.y)
        enemy = room.enemy
        print("You use {} against {}!".format(best_weapon.name,enemy.name))
        enemy.hp -=  best_weapon.damage

        if not enemy.is_alive():
            print("You killed {}!".format(enemy.name))
            
        else:
            print("{} HP is {}.".format(enemy.name,enemy.hp))

def heal(self):
    consumables = [item for item in self.inventory if isinstance(item,items.Consumables)]
    if not consumables:
        print("You dont have any items to heal you!")
        return 

    for i, item in enumerate(consumables, 1):
        print("Choose an item to use to heal: ")
        print("{}. {}".format(i, item))
    
    valid = False
    while not valid:
        choice = input("")
        try:
            to_eat = consumables[int(choice)-1]
            self.hp = min(100,self.hp + to_eat.healing_value)
            self.inventory.remove(to_eat)
            print("Current HP: {}".format(self.hp))
            valid = True
        except (ValueError,IndexError):
            print("Invalid choice, try again")

def trade(self):
    room = world.tile_at(self.x,self.y)
    room.check_if_trade(self)

def current_locaton(self):
    room = world.tile_at(self.x,self.y)
    self.current_location = room

def saveload(self):
    player_Stats = {
        self.player.hp,
        self.player.gold,
        self.player.lvl,
        self.player.current_location(),
    }
    filename = 'save.json'
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(player_Stats)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit 19:42:15 22-09-2020

You are not pointing to the file/stream where you want to save it.

```
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(player_Stats, f)
```

OR

```
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(player_Stats))
```

Let us know if that helps.

Comment: down at the bottom i have a function called LoadSave() right now i was just attempting to get it to save a few parameters just to see if it makes the json.